# Phlorizin content in grapes

Tags: biochemistry

I work in a winery and we have some problems about a new process involving phlorizin. We know that phlorizin is the major dihydrochalcone found in apples.

I have been reading that this compound is also found in a grape named Albariño, a white variety of grape. What else is known about the phlorizin content in grapes?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlorizin

Comment: https://www.bio-conferences.org/articles/bioconf/pdf/2016/02/bioconf-oiv2016_02006.pdf